# Set 'dependsOn' for nested fields in keystoneJS

Tags: javascript, mongoose, keystonejs

How do I set 'dependsOn' for a nested field?

This wont work...

```
Model.add({
    title:          { type: String, required: true },
    test1:          { type: Boolean, default: false },
    verify1:        { type: String, dependsOn: { test1: false } },
    nested: {
        test2:      { type: Boolean, default: false },
        verify2:    { type: String, dependsOn: { test2: false } },
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried a few things. Not only do you have to include the path, but you have to treat it as a string.

This works...

```
Model.add({
    title:          { type: String, required: true },
    test1:          { type: Boolean, default: false },
    verify1:        { type: String, dependsOn: { test1: false } },
    nested: {
        test2:      { type: Boolean, default: false },
        verify2:    { type: String, dependsOn: { 'nested.test2': false } },
    }
});
```